# AngularJS + CherryPy GET return nothing

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest, cherrypy

I try to use cherryPy (return JSON) with angularJS.

on the cherryPY side I use the [example code](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorial/REST.html?highlight=restful)

```
import cherrypy
import json
inputs = [
    {
        'title': 'Lumberjack Song',
        'artist': 'Canadian Guard Choir'
    },
    {
        'title': 'Other Song',
        'artist': 'artist'
    }
]    
class Inputs:
    exposed = True
    def GET(self, id=None):
        if id is None:
            cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            cherrypy.response.status = 200
            print('Retour: %s' % inputs)
            return(json.dumps(inputs))
        else:
            input = inputs[int(id)]
            cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            cherrypy.response.status = 200
            return(json.dumps(input))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.tree.mount(
        Inputs(), '/api/inputs',
            {'/':
                {'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher()}
            }
    )

    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
```

When I test this (with the Chrome REST plugin):

```
http://localhost:8080/api/inputs it return the correct JSON   information list of inputs
http://localhost:8080/api/inputs/1 it return the correct JSON input
```

I make an angularJS service :

```
    'use strict';       
    angular.module('RaspBerry.Services', ['ngResource']).factory('Inputs', function ($resource) {
      return $resource('http://localhost:port/api/inputs/:id', {"port":":9082"}, {
        'query': { method: 'GET', format:'json', isArray: true },
        'save': {method:'POST', isArray: false },
        'update': {method:'PUT', isArray: false },
        'delete': {method:'DELETE', isArray: false}
      });
});
// app.factory
```

the controller code

```
'use strict';
angular.module('RaspBerry.Controllers.Input_controller',[]).
  controller("EntreeListController", ["$scope", "$location", "Inputs", function($scope, $location, Inputs) {
    Inputs.query({},
      function (data, status) {
        $scope.entrees = data;
      },function (data, status) {
      }
    );
}]
).controller("EntreeDetailController",["$scope", "$window", "$resource", "$routeParams", "$location", "notify", "Inputs", function($scope, $window, $resource, $routeParams, $location, notify, Inputs) {
    Inputs.get({id:$routeParams.id},
      function (data, status) {
        $scope.input = data
      },
      function (input, status) {
        console.log("KO " + status);
      }
    );              
}]);
```

When I launch my application my service is always in error with a status = 0

Comment: dont' you need to pass an ID for `.get()`? If you want to list all isn't it `.query()`?

Comment: yes it is a mistake - but it is not the problem